# Level 2 Hardware Acceleration and webcam

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, webcam

I am creating a webcam air app. This app will also have some intense sprite animations.

Without Hardware Acceleration everything works fine, but my sprite animation is too cpu intensive.

When I enable Hardware Acceleration i get a 70% speed increase, but my webcam is no longer working. Is there anyway of telling flash to ignore the webcam on hardware acceleration? Or, what is it that I have to do?

Thank you very much for your help good sirs.

Answer (score 0):

try removing sprite animations from the display list and displaying them with [`BitmapData.draw()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) every frame instead